# How to post to url BUT redirect to other location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, post

My form is doing a POST to its action URL perfectly but when I submit the form it takes me to the URL of the POST.

I was wondering if I could still post to the action URL but redrect to another page?

I've tried using return false; but I'm still taken to the action URL.

Here's my code so far:

```
<form id="login" onSubmit="return login();">
  <input id="username" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  <input id="login-btn" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>

<script>
function login() {
  var url="actionurl";
  location.href=url;
  return false;
}
</script>
```

so i used this script on another app which posts to a php url and sends an email without leaving the page of the form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function () {
    $('form').submit( function () {
        var formdata = $(this).serialize();
         $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "http://myurl.com/email-form/send_form_email.php",
              data: formdata,
           });
         return false;
     });
 });
</script>
```

is there a way of modifying this to add the username and password variables entered from my login form on the this url https://www.myurl.com/index.php?option=com_hoicoiapi&task=login&

just a thought as it works on my email form.

PS it is important ?option=com_hoicoiapi&task=login& is on the url and that &username=test&pass=1234 comes from the form.

Comment: note that your redirect will fetch the new page as a GET, which means your POST data are going to be lost. perhaps everything is working fine, but you're redirecting to a page which requires the user to be logged in, and they never get logged in due to the redirect you do, so you get sent back to the login page.

Comment: Note that a `POST` request would actually require a `method="POST"` attribute on the form

Comment: so theres no way of doing a POST but going to a different page?

Comment: Sure there is, but you're not doing a POST to begin with ?

Comment: but the form is posting? sorry if i sound niave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to send the form with a `GET` request, which is what you're using, with ajax, and then redirect

```
var url_to_send_to  = 'actionurl';
var url_to_redirect = 'otherurl';

$('#login').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url  : url_to_send_to,
        type : "POST",
        data : $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        window.location.href = url_to_redirect
    });
});
```

And remove the inline event handler ,,,

Comment: `+11` for _"remove the inline event handler"_

Comment: so this worked when i tried making my action url facebook.com and my otherurl google.co.uk, it took me to google, :D

however i think the url im trying to post to it doesnt like,

now i know this is a really insecure way of logging in but besides that can you look at this url and tell me why it isnt posting or event redirecting its just adding ?username=test&password=test on to the end of the url im on

var url_to_send_to  = 'https://mysite/index.php?option=com_hoicoiapi&task=login&username=" + document.getElementById("username").value + "&pass=" + document.getElementById("password").value;

Comment: If you want to POST something, you add `method="post"` to your form, otherwise it will always be a GET request, with a querystring. To do the same in `$.ajax` you'd add a type, I'll edit the answer to add that. Note that catching a GET request and a POST request serverside, usually is a little different as well.

Comment: that redirects to other url perfectly :D BUT it doesnt seem to be doing the POST 

Here the code & url

<script>
var url_to_send_to  = "https://mysite/index.php?option=com_hoicoiapi&task=login&username=" + document.getElementById("username").value + "&pass=" + document.getElementById("password").value;
var url_to_redirect = '/index.html';

$('#login').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url  : url_to_send_to,
        type : "POST",
        data : $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        window.location.href = url_to_redirect
    });
});
</script>

Comment: You don't have to add the querystring, jQuery does that for you when serializing the form ?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot to that unless you perform the POST using AJAX and in the callback, you can redirect the browser using Javascript (document.location.href = 'someurl').

The only way to do this without resorting to Javascript is to have the POST url do a server-side redirect to your desired URL.